# How to delete row from a heap with a batch size 10000

Tags: sql-delete, azure-synapse

No supported-

```
DELETE TOP(10000) FROM dataArchival.MyTable 
    WHERE DateLocal BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-10-01'

delete dataArchival.MyTable
from dataArchival.MyTable d,#myTemp d2
where d.DateLocal=d2.DateLocal

delete d from dataArchival.MyTable d
(
 SELECT
        *,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM dataArchival.MyTable
    where DateLocal  BETWEEN '2018-03-01' AND '2018-10-01'
)A where A.RN <=10000
```

And ofcource CTE and @@rowcount are also not supported.

Comment: Your syntax seems ok. Maybe a trigger in MyTable? By the way, it says Line 4, is it the full exact code you are executing?

Comment: Yes,This is the only statement I am executing.And there are no triggers.

Comment: My bad delete with top is not supported. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

As per [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#examples--and-) Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not support `TOP(n)` with `DELETE` at this point:

```
-- Syntax for Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse  
DELETE FROM [database_name . [ schema ] . | schema. ] table_name    
    [ WHERE <search_condition> ]   
    [ OPTION ( <query_options> [ ,...n ]  ) ]  
[; ]
```

However you can script for a similar effect, eg this example is adapted from [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-loops#replacing-cursors-in-sql-data-warehouse) to delete by date:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
WITH ( 
DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
)
AS
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY ( SELECT NULL ) ) AS rowId,
    DateLocal
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT DateLocal FROM dataArchival.MyTable ) x;


DECLARE @sql_code NVARCHAR(4000) = 'DELETE dataArchival.MyTable WHERE DateLocal = @p1'
DECLARE @nbr_statements INT = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tmp ),
        @i INT = 1;


WHILE   @i <= @nbr_statements
BEGIN
    DECLARE @p1 DATE = ( SELECT DateLocal FROM #tmp WHERE rowId = @i );
    EXEC    sp_executesql @sql_code, N'@p1 DATE', @p1
    SET     @i +=1;
END
```

You could easily alter this example to delete in batches of 10,000 if deleting by date is unsatisfactory.  There is an additional example of batching up deletes here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-best-practices-transactions#minimize-logging-with-small-batches

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But the issue is there is no fixed number of records in my table for each date. This is an alternate solution in my mind, but I need a generic approach where I can delete 10,000 rows at a time irrespective of id column/date column.

Comment: This could be tricky if there is nothing else to filter by or group up into blocks of 10,000.  Can you post the rest of the schema and an idea of the number of records in the table etc?